# In activity voice input for Google glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I have been working on a product search application for glass and was wondering if glass would support the following:

Inside of an activity, after the glassware has already launched, I would like the app to prompt the user to say the name of a product, say "Apples". After the user speaks the app will have what the user spoke displayed in a textview inside of the activity.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I see that google itself uses a similar function to what I need here https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3086044?hl=en

Specifically: Your spoken message is transcribed into text and a preview of your message will appear in the display. 

any way we can get this functionality outside the messenger app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I needed here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/
Essentially it uses androids native voice to text to perform the translation. Pretty cool that it works on glass.